# Customizing WSO2 Governance Registry 4.6.0 - Service List

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I'm trying to customizing in WSO2 Governance Registry 4.6.0 (G-Reg) the "Service List" table (Home > Metadata > List > Services) adding two column from "Service detail view": "Overview - Description" and "Endpoints - URL"
I've edited the "Services Artifacts" (Home > Extensions > Configure > Artifact Types > Artifact Source) with the following lines:

```
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-service+xml" shortName="service" singularLabel="Service" pluralLabel="Services" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="27">
    <storagePath>/trunk/services/@{namespace}/@{name}</storagePath>
    <nameAttribute>overview_name</nameAttribute>
    <!--<endpoint1Attribute>endpointstext_endpoint1</endpoint1Attribute>-->
    <namespaceAttribute>overview_namespace</namespaceAttribute>
    <lifecycle>ServiceLifeCycle</lifecycle>
    <ui>
        <list>
            <column name="Service Name B">
                <data type="text" value="overview_name"/>
            </column>
            <!-- NEW Description -->
            <column name="Description">
                <data type="text" value="overview_description"/>
            </column>
            <!-- NEW Endpoints -->
            <column name="Endpoints">
                <!-- <data type="text" value="endpoints_endpoint1"/> -->
                <!-- <data type="text" value="endpointmgt_endpointstext_endpoint1"/> -->
                <data type="text" value="endpoints_endpointstext_endpoint1"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Version">
                <data type="path" value="overview_version" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Namespace">
                <data type="text" value="overview_namespace"/>
            </column>
        </list>
    </ui>
    <content>
    ......
    </content>
</artifactType>
```

The column "Descrition" is filled properly, while column "Endpoints" is empty.
How to value the tag value?(data type="text" value="???????"/>) ??

Comment: Did my below answer solved the issue? Please let me know if you want more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add unbounded table values to list view. But if you really want see the endpoint value in the list create a new text filed and replicate the same value.

```
<list>
            <column name="Service Name">
                <data type="text" value="overview_name"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Version">
                <data type="path" value="overview_version" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Service Namespace">
                <data type="text" value="overview_namespace"/>
            </column>
            <column name="Endpoint">
                <data type="text" value="endpoints_endpoint"/>
            </column>
        </list>
```

and update the endpoints table like below

```
<table name="Endpoints">
            <subheading>
                <heading>Environments</heading>
                <heading>URL</heading>
            </subheading>
            <field type="option-text" maxoccurs="unbounded" url="true">
                <name label="Endpoint">Endpoint</name>
                <values>
                    <value>None</value>
                    <value>Unknown</value>
                    <value>Dev</value>
                    <value>Test</value>
                    <value>Stag</value>
                    <value>Prod</value>
                </values>
            </field>

            <field type="text">
                <name label="Endpoint">Endpoint</name>
            </field>
        </table>
```

Now you can see endpoint value in the list.

[image: GReg service List view]

To create your own RXTs please find [this article](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-create-new-artifacts-type-in.html).